# MVC6 error The name 'Configuration' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core

I have attempted to re-write my DbContext from EF Core to EF6 to work with my supported database by following the following documentation:
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/data/entity-framework-6.html

However I receive the error `The name 'Configuration' does not exist in the current context` based on the following line of code in my Startup.cs:

> services.AddScoped((_) => new
>   PortalUserContext(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

#### UPDATE

I have added the System.Configuration.dll to the solution's references which causes a new error `'Configuration' is a type, which is not valid in the given context NextGenPortal`
`

Comment: Please share the code for your Startup class and mention the version of your asp.net project, which version of asp.net core? as you should have a property called Configuration

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue when trying to add Configuration to an asp.net core project. I eventually ran into this blog post that explains how to define that Configuration property, which for some strange reason is not covered in the asp.net core documentation.

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/284/asp-net-5-configuration

Basically you need to define this property in your Startup class and then instantiate it in the constructor with the corresponding config file. The article is a bit outdated but it's easier to figure out the parts that changed. Like the signature for the Startup constructor.